# Find the subgroup $\langle\{6,8\}\rangle$ in $(\mathbb {Z},+)$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Find the subgroup $\langle\{6,8\}\rangle$ in $(\mathbb {Z},+)$.

This was a problem given in a book about group theory . I think the notation $\langle S\rangle$ stands for a set $S$ stands for a group (or subgroup) generated by $S$.Here, $S=\{6,8\}$.My solution goes like this:

> If $H=\langle\{6,8\}\rangle$ is a subgroup in $(\mathbb {Z},+)$ then $$\langle \{6,8\}\rangle=\{6k,8k,2k,14k| k\in\mathbb {Z}\}=H$$ . This is because,  $H$ is generated by $\langle\{6,8\}\rangle$ and $H$ is a subgroup, so $$8^n=8+8+...+8\space (\text{n times})=8n\in H$$($\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$), due to which $8k\in H$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ . Similarly,  $6k\in H$ . Also, $8-6=2\in H$ as $-6\in H$ and hence $2k\in H$ and $8+6=14\in H$ so, $14k\in H$ . Now, since $14k,6k,8k\subset 2k$ hence ,$H=\{2k|k\in\mathbb {Z}\}$.

Is the above solution correct? Is it a correct method for solving this type of problems ?Is it valid ? If not, where is it going wrong? Also, there may be some posts relating to this topic on this site but I can't seem to find it either...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140694/discussion-on-question-by-franklin-find-the-subgroup-langle-6-8-rangle-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all non-trivial subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ are
$$
m\mathbb{Z} = \{ mk \ |\ k \in \mathbb{Z} \}
$$
for any positive integer $m$.

Now, the generated set from $S = \{6,8\}$ is
$$
\langle S \rangle = \{ 6p + 8q \ |\ p,q \in \mathbb{Z} \}\ .
$$
Since $\text{gcd}(6,8) = 2$, we know that there exist integers $p_0$ and $q_0$ such that
$$
2 = 6p_0 + 8q_0\ ,
$$
so $2 \in \langle S \rangle$. But then, for any integer $k$,
$$
2k = 6p_0k + 8q_0k \in \langle S \rangle\ ,
$$
so we can rewrite the generated set as
$$
\langle S \rangle = \{ 2k \ |\ k \in \mathbb{Z} \}\ ,
$$
which is the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you! So , my solution goes valid as well , right ?...